# Can I add an arbitrary RSS feed to Flipboard?

Tags: ipad

Would you please confirm that it is not possible to add an arbitrary RSS feed to Flipboard on my iPad? I find this so hard to believe that I'm in doubt I missed something...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, it can be done very easily: Just put the name of the feed, or its URL, in the search box. Flipboard will find it. And then, you can select it, and add it.

Comment: Hooray for improvements to Flipboard! (I promise my answer was correct a year earlier.)

Comment: @passerby This does not work for every feed. For example `http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/` feed. It says `Sorry, we couldn't find the page you were looking for.`!

Comment: If your website is not showing just make sure you have removed http and www from the URL

Answer (score 6):

Actually you CAN load a specific feed to Flipboard.  Start by adding Google Reader.  Then launch into it, and click on the downward facing Triangle next to the headline "Google Reader."  It will then pop up a window showing you your various feeds.  Select the one you want, and its name will appear as the new headline and you will only see stories from that feed.  Then click the little "+ content" symbol in the upper left, and it'll add just this single RSS feed to your main flipboard page.

Comment: wow, this is actually very cool! thanks for pointing out. however, i think passerby's answer is the most correct, because it tells how to add a feed _directly_, without resorting to google reader. imagine a dystopian world, where a user hasn't a google account... :)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that you cannot add an arbitrary feed, and as @Mike Scott noted, you have to add your entire Google Reader account.

Frustrating because Flipboard is absolutely not a good way for me to read the bulk of my feeds -- Reeder is perfect for them -- but I'd love to add a few feeds that I rarely read to Flipboard, feeds that fit its visual style.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really like flipboard, but this policy makes no sense to me. After all, _it is_ a newsreader...

Comment: i'm sorry i unaccepted your answer; flipboard has been updated, i guess, and it is now possible to add an arbitrary feed.

Comment: @ffact Totally fine, that's how SE works: answers that were once true but no longer are should definitely be unaccepted!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an arbitrary RSS feed by creating a Google Reader account, adding the feed to that, and then linking it with Flipboard.

Comment: Good point. Sadly unpractical.

Comment: Unpractical? You can do this very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

From the Flipboard tips page:

> Discover Great RSS Feeds.
>   You can use the Google Reader service to access RSS and then read and interact with your feeds right in Flipboard.  You can also use the Search feature to find any RSS feed by name, website URL, or RSS link.

Answer (score 1):

More to the original point, unlike Twitter, Google Reader is not fully integrated with Flipboard as you can not add RSS feed to your Google Reader on your iPad app. Disappointing as Google Reader is a best archiver/database of all feeds you are following.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's based on blekko.com cached search result which may not be up to dated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Could you clarify what you mean by this and give us more details? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.